# cstdint file not found when building on the command line

Tags: c++, xcode, xcodebuild, cinder, cstdint

I'm trying to build a couple of projects on the command like but I keep getting screwed up by an failure to find `<cstdint>`. The project tries to build an when it gets to a specific line in the include path, specifically `#include <cstdint>` it throws an error

```
fatal error: 'cstdint' file not found.
```

This is baffling because this file is in my home path it looks like but it can't be found. I really don't know that much about compilers and paths so please excuse my ignorance.

A little background about my computer and what I'm trying to run. It is a MacBook Pro and I'm running Xcode 4.6.2. The framework that I'm building against is the Cinder framework and the file that is throwing the error is `Cinder.h`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you compiling against C++11?

Comment: what is the full command you used ?

Comment: @Sander - xcodebuild -alltargets. millsj - I'm not sure how to set the build compiler

Answer (score 1):

You must build with -std=c++0x

Comment: I put it after -alltargets and it still didn't build.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the `cstdint` file can be found in `/usr/include/c++`, for example:

```
% find /usr -name cstdint
/usr/include/c++/12/cstdint
/usr/include/c++/12/tr1/cstdint
/usr/include/c++/11/cstdint
/usr/include/c++/11/tr1/cstdint
```

They belong to packages such as `libstdc++-11-dev`, possibly conflicting others:

```
% dpkg -S /usr/include/c++/11/cstdint
libstdc++-11-dev:amd64: /usr/include/c++/11/cstdint

% dpkg -S /usr/include/c++/12/cstdint
libstdc++-12-dev:amd64: /usr/include/c++/12/cstdint
```